# Are there any artifacts for filesystem forensics in memory?

Tags: forensics, memory, file-system

I have a memory dump. I know it is infected by a rootkit which uses its own file system installed at the end of the disk. Can there be any artifacts in dmp file to show this?

Comment: Can you define what "this" is at the end of your sentence?

Comment: sorry for my english! I mean is there any way I can follow to know a file in memory comes from a main filesystem and another file has been loaded from sectors out of the filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

The answer all depends on the rootkit and how it operated. There **WILL BE** remnants, but whether they are visible, encrypted, mangled, etc., are another story. Since you have a memory image, you can analyze it with Volatility, carve out data from the dmp with [psdispscan](https://code.google.com/p/volatility/wiki/CommandReference22#psdispscan) if you can detect the anomaly from the memory. You could also use [scalpel](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Scalpel) to do this but again, you need something to base your carvings on.

Had I to perform these tasks, I'd use a combination of Volatility, [Memoryze](https://www.mandiant.com/resources/download/memoryze), and [Redline](https://www.mandiant.com/resources/download/redline). I would try to carve out as many processes as possible, any anomalies, and perhaps shove some of them through [Virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com/) or [Anubis](https://anubis.iseclab.org/). It all depends on my objective(s). So the short answer, yes there will be remnants, the conclusive answer: There are remnants you may not be able to see.

Answer (score 0):

You can hash/extract each artifact (in a VM) and compare that with [a malware database](https://isc.sans.edu/tools/hashsearch.html). I assume you have already taken a forensically sound image of the system of course.